# JAVA RMI Client

Tags: java, rmi

I have the problem that my RMI Application Client isn't working when i hit the "run" Button in Eclipse. It throws the following exception:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: rsrc
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Unknown Source)
...
```

I looked on the internet and people seem to have that problem when generating JARs from eclipse. But my (ant-built) jars work fine, just inside Eclipse it's not doing as it should!

```
 InterfaceRemota objetoRemoto = (InterfaceRemota)Naming.lookup("//localhost:1097/ObjetoRemoto");
```

Comment: "unknown protocol: rsrc". Sure you shouldn't specify protocol inside lookup? Just guessing

Comment: you may want to add more client & server code. It is very vague to spot the problem in the one liner code

Comment: Are you sure that's the code that is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, before starting the rmiregistry server I have to clean the java classpath using "set CLASSPATH="

c: > set CLASSPATH=

c: > rmiregistry