# RMI Server-side java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c

Tags: java, server, rmi, malformedurlexception

I surfed the net for 2 days, and I didn't find a solution formyproblem, so I decided to ask here.
I'm doing a book exercise: "Write a program Client-Server with Java RMI, that return the sum of integer given by clients. It has to implement a method to add an integer, anda method to get the total".
I'm facing with the Server-side.

The error the program returns is:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.Naming.bind(Unknown Source)
at ContatoreServer.main(ContatoreServer.java:15)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.pathToURLs(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.getDefaultCodebaseURLs(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

Here there are my classes:
**LocalObject**

```
public class ContatoreLocale {
    private int num;

    public ContatoreLocale(){
        this.num=0;
    }

    public synchronized int get(){
        return this.num;
    }

    public synchronized void add(int i){
        this.num+=i;
    }
}
```

**Remote Interface**

```
public interface IContatore extends Remote{
    int get() throws RemoteException;
    void add(int i) throws RemoteException;

}
```

**Remote Object**

```
public class ContatoreRemoto extends ContatoreLocale implements IContatore{
    Logger log= Logger.getLogger("global");

    //Costruttore
    public ContatoreRemoto() throws RemoteException{
        super();
        UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, 0);
        try {
            Naming.rebind("Contatore", this);
            //errore
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    public int get(String nome) throws RemoteException{
        return this.get();
    }

    public void add(String nome,int i) throws RemoteException{
        this.add(i);
    }
}
```

**Server**

```
public class ContatoreServer {
    static Logger log= Logger.getLogger("global");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                ContatoreRemoto cr=new ContatoreRemoto();
                log.info("Server Pronto");
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Please, help me :S

Comment: This might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325702/java-rmi-client

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AnkurChrungoo I'm launching the rmiregistry as an External Tool in Eclipse, so I don't know how to manage the solution you proposed

Comment: `Namng.rebind()` requires a URL, not just a name. You need `"//localhost/Contatore"`, or at least `"Contatore"`.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, this has to do with the absolute path in the File System where the RMI Eclipse project is placed. I think you may have a blank, a space, in the path. So RMI is unable to parse the path and it is interrupted, ... then we get the 'malformed' exception. It might be near a 'c', and for this reason, you get the 'c' in the exception.
I recommend you go to the file system, navigate to the project folder, and check the absolute path to the project. I bet you have a blank.
Such as c:\Users\mylab c\MyProjects....
Did you notice the blank space?

Comment: `Naming.rebind()` threw the exception, and makes no use of file system paths.